# How to encrypt every name in a list ZSH scripting using a for loop

Tags: zsh

I'm new to zsh scripting and I was wondering if it's possible to use the sha256sum function to encrypt every value in a list.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#!/bin/zsh

filenames=`cat filenames.txt`
output='shaNames.txt'

for name in $filenames
do
    echo -n $name | sha256sum >> $output
done
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to encrypt every name in the list and append it to a new text file.

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the output of `cat filenames.txt` to a multiline variable. The for loop will then only loop once over the content.
What you want to do instead is e.g.:

```
for name in $(cat filenames.txt)
do
echo -n "$name" | sha256sum >> "$output"
done
```

Note that while you can still use them, [backticks are deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) in favor of `$(somecommand)`.

Also note that you should always put variables in double quotes, as they could contain spaces.

Your method would fail anyways if one line of your textfile would contain a space.
You could use the following instead:

```
while read name
do
echo -n "$name" | sha256sum >> "$output"
done < filenames.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who might need the same. What I was doing wrong was assigning the values in the file to a single string variable instead of a list.

To correct that one must use:

```
filenames=(`cat filenames.txt`)
```

The parenthesis indicates that a list or array is stored in the filenames variable.

Comment: While that approach would work, it is unnecessary to save the data to an intermediate array. Also see the part of my answer about backticks.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I’ll keep it in mind.

Comment: This still would fail if the files have a space in their name.